# Objective-C: how to list files in individual UITableViewCells?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Bellow I have some code that retrieves files from the documents directory where my application is stored on the idevice. It then successfully retrieves that path to the file which is a mp4 because that is what I am storing. And does this by displaying the filename in a cell of the `UiTableView` I have created . However the code only displays one file in one cell. But I want to list multiple files individually in there own cell so eventually the user can individually select that cell depending on the video file they want.

**Here is the code that retrieves and displays the file directory of the file but does not list more then one file in the table:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];


}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(!filePathsArray)  // if data loading has been completed, return the number of rows ELSE return 1
    {

        if ([filePathsArray count] > 0)
            return [filePathsArray count];
        else
            return 1;
    }

    return 1;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
    cell.textLabel.text = [filePathsArray[indexPath.row] lastPathComponent];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: `if(!filePathsArray) { if ([filePathsArray count] > 0)`

Comment: Don't repost the same question. If needed, update your previous question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(!filePathsArray)
    {
        if ([filePathsArray count] > 0)
            return [filePathsArray count];
        else
            return 1;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Should read:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [filePathsArray count];
}
```

Comment: Every path in your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` implementation returns the same value as `[filePathsArray count]`.  If `filePathsArray` is nil then the `count` message, being sent to nil, will return 0.  If `[filePathsArray count] == 0` then the equivalence is obvious, and the count method returns an `NSUInteger` so the only options are `[filePathsArray count] > 0` or `[filePathsArray count] == 0` (`[filePathsArrayCount count]` can't return less than zero, if you were trying to clamp negative values to 0).

Comment: @AaronGolden Yup that's true, I was just writing the code super fast and copy pasted some of his code in. Didn't think about that. Fixed in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be returning `[filePathsArray count];` from your `numberOfRowsInSection` method under normal circumstances.  Right now you're actually returning 1 from that method in all cases.  I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do with the logic at the top of your `numberOfRowsInSection` method, but I think you should start by just replacing the whole body of the method with `return [filePathsArray count];`.

One more thing:  You have a comment in there "if data loading has completed," but all the work in the code you posted is going synchronously on the main thread.  By the time your `viewDidLoad` method has completed your `filePathsArray` is initialized.  You don't need to do anything tricky to account for a case where `filePathsArray` is still nil, unless you're worried about the table view loading data before the view controller's view has actually loaded.  But that would be very weird.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you initializing filePathsArray over and over again first under viewDidLoad and then under tableview.

This is how I would write the code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//initializing array and getting values the first time when page loads.
    filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];


}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

//return whatever the count of this array is. no need to do any if! checks  
return [filePathsArray count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [filePathsArray[indexPath.row] lastPathComponent];
    return cell;
}
```